# ASP.NET Website accessible locally but not from a an external IP (302 response in logs instead of 200)

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I am trying to host an ASP.NET website on IIS for a customer. I can access the website by IP/domain locally but not when using another device (another IP).

Here are all the details that are worth mentioning:

- Ports are open (Checked with telnet)
- Using Application Pool identity
- Logs under `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2` show: 200 response for local IP but 302 response for all remote IPs.
- Accessing the default IIS website works locally and remotely

Any clues why this may be happening? I already spent more than 6 hours on this so I am willing to try any guess at this point.

*PS: I am totally novice when it comes to IIS and ASP.NET*

Comment: FRT might tell you more about what happens, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing but you do need to learn enough about IIS/ASP.NET so as to interpret the logs. Talk to the site developer(s) or hire an experienced consultant if you can.

Comment: 302 is a redirect, have you set redirect rules for the website?

Comment: I guess that I will go with the option of asking an ASP.NET developer. I am pretty sure it is not an IIS configuration issue because I literally copied every single setting from the old server where the website was working. I must be missing something silly within the ASP.NET website due to my lack of knowledge that is causing the redirect. I will answer my question if I manage to find the solution. Thank you for those who commented and suggested some options.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: I got a developer to get the issue fixed. I already emailed him to get a proper explanation of what was the issue. I will answer my question as soon as I get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a **HTTP to HTTPS redirection**. Since I moved the website to another server where the SSL certificate was not installed yet and HTTPS not configured, it was inaccessible. I had no clue since I did not even enable HSTS in IIS but I guess that there was some kind of redirection within the website's ASP.NET config itself.

Anyways, even though I'm still unable to explain why it worked locally at first but all what matters is that the cause of the issue was found.